# What is the correct way to protect fields in an Entity Framework model?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a model class where I want the Id to be read only and I want a string property to have a backing field (to apply Trim to set values). What is the correct way to do this?

```
public class DisallowedEmail
{
    private string _email;

    public int Id { get; }
    public required string Email
    {
        get => _email;
        set => _email = value.Trim();
    }

    private DisallowedEmail(int id, string email)
    {
        Id = id;
        _email = email;
    }

    public DisallowedEmail()
    {
        _email = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

or...

```
public class DisallowedEmail
{
    private string _email;

    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public required string Email
    {
        get => _email;
        set => _email = value.Trim();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was suspecting that the first one wouldn't work as Id would need a setter for the constructor to set. However, that said I decided to test it and while it compiles, it actually didn't work when I tried the below example which does work with a private setter. (It complained about not finding a suitable constructor, even though the constructor didn't change)

EF Core supports using constructor arguments, and will discover/use private constructors so you can exert more control over ensuring that entities are constructed in a valid state.

For example, EF would need a constructor or public/protected property setters to  populate state from the database when constructing entities. You may want a public or internal (if using a Factory pattern) constructor for code to initialize a new instance, ensuring a valid and complete state.

Say you have a Customer entity and customers have a set of required fields including a billing address (entity) as well as some optional fields:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int CustomerId { get; private set; } = 0;

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public string? PreferredName { get; set; } = null;

    public virtual Address BillingAddress { get; protected set; }

    // Constructor EF will use.
    protected Customer(int customerId, string name)
    {
        CustomerId = customerId;
        Name = name;
    }

    // Constructor consumers or factories will use. (could be internal for factory use)
    public Customer(string name, Address billingAddress)
    {
        Name = name;
        BillingAddress = billingAddress;
    }
}
```

The EF constructor can be `private` but only so long as you don't enable proxies. Otherwise it needs to be `protected` which honestly is protected enough IMO and a safer option.

The distinction here is that while EF can use constructors to initialize entities, it cannot use constructors that reference navigation properties. For our public setup of new customers we may want to ensure that code supplies a billing address as that is a required field. We may also guard changing a billing address behind a method that will validate it, or perform some other actions like updating a change history etc. rather than a simple setter. We don't want consumers to see the version EF does as they will not have an ID for a new customer, nor should we encourage "hacky" behaviour like populating and attaching customers assumed to be representing live data.

Comment: First off, thanks. Second, the navigation, and any other properties, will be set with a setter after the constructor is called - correct? In your example, PreferredName and BillingAddress?

Comment: Also, asking your opinion as I'm new to EF, do you think constructors are good, or is it better to have it initialize everything with setters?

Comment: Sorry, third question. How do you know EF will use the first constructor? Is it because that's the only way to initialize customerId? Or because it is protected? From what I've read (again, this is all new to me) EF can use a private setter to initialize a property???

Comment: Yes, navigation properties would generally be set via setters. The decision to use constructors and access modifiers (protected/internal/private) really just comes down to how much control you want to enforce on accessibility. The simplest thing is public getters/setters but that leaves the entity open to be initialized/modified into an incomplete or invalid state. Design approaches like DDD look for ways to introduce structure to align data to business processes and generally reduce the temptation or risk of misuse.

Comment: EF checks over all available constructors to figure out if it can use them. It uses reflection and can see private constructors but things like proxies won't be able to work with them, so protected is generally the safer option. If you want to keep constructors simple and use factory methods instead, then I'd often leave setters marked `internal`. This also works nicely for unit tests that will want to initialize entities as if they were coming from EF. (Combined with InternalsVisibleTo)

Answer (score 0):

For your concrete usecase, it would be simplest have one constructor which you use to create the entity, during which you trim the email address, and the second constructor which the EntityFramework will use to create the entity when reading it from the database.

```cs
public class DisallowedEmail
{
    // Properties
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Address { get; private set; }
        
    // Constructors
    public DisallowedEmail(string address)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(address))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(address));
        }
        Address = address.Trim();
    }

#pragma warning disable CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.
    /// <summary>Constructor for EntityFrameworkCore.</summary>
    /// <remarks>EntityFrameworkCore chooses the constructor with the least amount of parameters (including 0) where all of them correspond to a property.</remarks>
    private DisallowedEmail() { }
#pragma warning restore CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.
}
```

Also, if you'd like some proper DotNet email address validation and cleanup, you can use my extension method [`string.ToEmailAddress()`](https://github.com/ErroneousFatality/Libraries/blob/50990eb265b37f23b190548f556045dd180a357b/DotNet/Extensions/StringExtensions.cs#L80) by either copying it or using [my Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AndrejKrizan.DotNet) which contains it (it's pure C# and doesn't have any dependencies):

```cs
using AndrejKrizan.DotNet.Extensions;

namespace Domain.Entities
{
    public class DisallowedEmail
    {
        // Properties
        public int Id { get; private set; }
        public string Address { get; private set; }
        
        // Constructors
        public DisallowedEmail(string address)
        {
            Address = address.ToEmailAddress();
        }

#pragma warning disable CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.
        /// <summary>Constructor for EntityFrameworkCore.</summary>
        /// <remarks>EntityFrameworkCore chooses the constructor with the least amount of parameters (including 0) where all of them correspond to a property.</remarks>
        private DisallowedEmail() { }
#pragma warning restore CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.
    }
}
```

Comment: I need the Email setter to trim so when the code sets the value from what is entered in the web page, that entered value is trimmed.

Comment: @DavidThielen you should do that on the presentation layer (where your web (api) controllers live), and have the domain layer containing the entity code work like this. Create something like a request or viewModel class to handle the interaction with the web page, then have your business logic layer create the entity. It's not wise to use one class for both presentation, business logic and persistence.

Comment: We disagree on if it's appropriate to put this Trim() call in the model. I prefer to have that in the model so my data layer is enforcing everything it can.